# Barycentric weighting of a point in a mesh

Tags: discrete-geometry, weights

I know there is a way to get a barycentric weighting of a point $p$ inside a convex polygon; for weighting $\omega_n$ of component $q_n$ with adjacent angles $\gamma_n$ and $\delta_n$:

$$\omega_n = \frac{cot(\gamma_n) + cot(\delta_n)}{∥p − q_n∥^2}$$

How could I do it with one or two additional components inside the polygon?

I know I can calculate every possible triangle, sum them up, and scale them down by their squared weightings to get $\sum\omega = 1$, but that is much too inefficient and time consuming (10 components is already 120 triangles) for what I'm trying to do.

Is there a better approach?